# How can I open database file in R?

Tags: r

I downloaded a database file from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyePj.png)

https://github.com/iDEP-SDSU/idep

I changed the file name to shorter name to successfully unzip the file.
Then I changed the file name again to 'convertIDs.db'

I am trying to connect the database to R using RSQLite package & dbConnect function.

code :

```
library(RSQLite, verbose=FALSE)
setwd('C:/idep/')
sqlite <- dbDriver('SQLite')
convert <- dbConnect(sqlite,paste0(datapath,"convertIDs.db"),flags=SQLITE_RO) # read only mode
```

but this produces warning message like:

> "Couldn't set synchronous mode:file is not a database"

How could i make R recognize the file as database file?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7rfI.png)

I have checked the file type - I checked the attribute of the file "Data Base File(.db)"

[File type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGrC6.png)

I checked if the file does exist on the path with file.exists("./data/data96/convertIDs.db"), this returned TRUE.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Check this link https://datacarpentry.org/R-ecology-lesson/05-r-and-databases.html

Comment: What's `sqlite` in your `dbConnect` call?

Comment: @Spacedman
`sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")`

Comment: @Binara Medawatta Thank you. I've checked the link. I tried with different codes but  still not working. I edited the post.